# Docker not mounting host files

Tags: docker, permissions

I'm trying to use a docker image from [here](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/data-science-quickstart-with-docker/) to start setting up a datascience set up. I can get docker to mount the container using

```
docker run -d --privileged=true -p 8888:8888 --name ipyn3 -v /home/repos/DoSomeData/:/home/ds/notebooks/ dataquestio/python3-starter
```

where the host directory "DoSomeData" contains a single folder at the moment "Hillary_Emails" which contains a directory of input data and a single iPython Notebook file.

When I go into ipython notebook, it can see the "Hillary_Emails" directory but nothing else. This is also the case when I log into the container using Bash and run ls. It appears to only be copying over the directory.
Running `docker inspect ipyn3` gives

```
[
{
    "Id": "b1cbba654135d46170e78c8ac522601ee743e1b1d3959b10fc7784c57c696433",
    "Created": "2016-03-14T20:20:24.413863418Z",
    "Path": "/home/ds/run_ipython.sh",
    "Args": [],
    "State": {
        "Status": "running",
        "Running": true,
        "Paused": false,
        "Restarting": false,
        "OOMKilled": false,
        "Dead": false,
        "Pid": 7629,
        "ExitCode": 0,
        "Error": "",
        "StartedAt": "2016-03-14T20:20:25.344852732Z",
        "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    },
    "Image": "sha256:3cccab0c85e256d355fd7facbf3b897363bb72f7089ce7d65c54fe55b69ea25d",
    "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/b1cbba654135d46170e78c8ac522601ee743e1b1d3959b10fc7784c57c696433/resolv.conf",
    "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/b1cbba654135d46170e78c8ac522601ee743e1b1d3959b10fc7784c57c696433/hostname",
    "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/b1cbba654135d46170e78c8ac522601ee743e1b1d3959b10fc7784c57c696433/hosts",
    "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/b1cbba654135d46170e78c8ac522601ee743e1b1d3959b10fc7784c57c696433/b1cbba654135d46170e78c8ac522601ee743e1b1d3959b10fc7784c57c696433-json.log",
    "Name": "/ipyn3",
    "RestartCount": 0,
    "Driver": "devicemapper",
    "MountLabel": "",
    "ProcessLabel": "",
    "AppArmorProfile": "",
    "ExecIDs": null,
    "HostConfig": {
        "Binds": [
            "/home/repos/DoSomeData/:/home/ds/notebooks/"
        ],
        "ContainerIDFile": "",
        "LogConfig": {
            "Type": "json-file",
            "Config": {}
        },
        "NetworkMode": "default",
        "PortBindings": {
            "8888/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "",
                    "HostPort": "8888"
                }
            ]
        },
        "RestartPolicy": {
            "Name": "no",
            "MaximumRetryCount": 0
        },
        "VolumeDriver": "",
        "VolumesFrom": null,
        "CapAdd": null,
        "CapDrop": null,
        "Dns": [],
        "DnsOptions": [],
        "DnsSearch": [],
        "ExtraHosts": null,
        "GroupAdd": null,
        "IpcMode": "",
        "Links": null,
        "OomScoreAdj": 0,
        "PidMode": "",
        "Privileged": true,
        "PublishAllPorts": false,
        "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
        "SecurityOpt": null,
        "UTSMode": "",
        "ShmSize": 67108864,
        "ConsoleSize": [
            0,
            0
        ],
        "Isolation": "",
        "CpuShares": 0,
        "CgroupParent": "",
        "BlkioWeight": 0,
        "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
        "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
        "CpuPeriod": 0,
        "CpuQuota": 0,
        "CpusetCpus": "",
        "CpusetMems": "",
        "Devices": [],
        "KernelMemory": 0,
        "Memory": 0,
        "MemoryReservation": 0,
        "MemorySwap": 0,
        "MemorySwappiness": -1,
        "OomKillDisable": false,
        "PidsLimit": 0,
        "Ulimits": null
    },
    "GraphDriver": {
        "Name": "devicemapper",
        "Data": {
            "DeviceId": "57",
            "DeviceName": "docker-253:0-2228497-91a65d788ceb1e1ed5a1ec339d19ba8de24ec574fad57982f6d939ec572df526",
            "DeviceSize": "10737418240"
        }
    },
    "Mounts": [
        {
            "Source": "/home/repos/DoSomeData",
            "Destination": "/home/ds/notebooks",
            "Mode": "",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": "rprivate"
        }
    ],
    "Config": {
        "Hostname": "b1cbba654135",
        "Domainname": "",
        "User": "ds",
        "AttachStdin": false,
        "AttachStdout": false,
        "AttachStderr": false,
        "ExposedPorts": {
            "8888/tcp": {}
        },
        "Tty": false,
        "OpenStdin": false,
        "StdinOnce": false,
        "Env": [
            "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
            "TERM=xterm",
            "LANG=en_US.UTF-8",
            "HOME=/home/ds",
            "SHELL=/bin/bash",
            "USER=ds"
        ],
        "Cmd": [
            "/home/ds/run_ipython.sh"
        ],
        "Image": "dataquestio/python3-starter",
        "Volumes": {
            "/home/ds/notebooks": {}
        },
        "WorkingDir": "/home/ds/notebooks",
        "Entrypoint": null,
        "OnBuild": null,
        "Labels": {},
        "StopSignal": "SIGTERM"
    },
    "NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "",
        "SandboxID": "84a7df65aa857432cc7bfcb7c28016eb40eee10c9a6eaf30c46fec3b69f2f673",
        "HairpinMode": false,
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "Ports": {
            "8888/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "8888"
                }
            ]
        },
        "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/84a7df65aa85",
        "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
        "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
        "EndpointID": "c8fe87fc450a97422439751ae1400f44c28656a81375788be214d4b5c7b70686",
        "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
        "IPPrefixLen": 16,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
        "Networks": {
            "bridge": {
                "IPAMConfig": null,
                "Links": null,
                "Aliases": null,
                "NetworkID": "7c709634cd55286747ac4080457e57290db1cdc774d290f59727436223ecf08a",
                "EndpointID": "c8fe87fc450a97422439751ae1400f44c28656a81375788be214d4b5c7b70686",
                "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                "IPv6Gateway": "",
                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02"
            }
        }
    }
}
]
```

Does anyone know what is causing this? I'm running Fedora23 and this is the first time I've tried using docker containers. Is it something to do with how permissions are propagating?

Thanks

Comment: Changing the `run` command to `docker run -d --privileged=true -p 8888:8888 --name ipyn3 -v $(pwd):/home/ds/notebooks/ dataquestio/python3-starter` has allowed me to see files. I would prefer to be able to run my command from anywhere however.

Answer (score 1):

I ran `docker inspect ipyn3` when it was working. Issue was that the source path needed my username after host i.e.

```
\home\user_name\repos\DoSomeData
```